# Склоняется ли название села Столбище

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Возник спор: склоняется ли название села Столбище. Прошу пояснить со ссылкой на соответствующие правила русского языка.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте сначала разберемся с формами **без родового слова**.
По правилам - склоняется. Ссылки вам дали, не буду повторяться.

Но при попытке абсолютного следования таким правилам возникают сложности. Вам понятны без контекста фразы типа "подъехал к Столбищу" - или "Выехал из Столбища"? Язык не шершавит? Все дело в том, что суффикс -ище не очень продуктивен в современном языке и склонение таких слов несвободно. 
Да еще использование без родового слова оставляет некоторый простор для интерпретации. Как оно там называется: *Столбище*, *Столбища* - или вообще *Столбищ*? Я не уверен, что все носители языка прочувствуют тут "-ище".

Поэтому без родового слова "село" использовать я бы вообще не советовал (хотя бы в первый раз в конкретном контексте). Но как быть при согласовании **с родовым словом**? Вот тут я категорически не согласен с Jasmin - и советую не склонять. У самой Jasmin приводится правило, что в случаях, когда род топонима (установленного по аналогии с омонимичным именем нарицательным) не совпадает с грамматическим родом родового слова, то согласования не происходит.

А что такое "столбище"? Это всего лишь большой столб. И не следует смешивать с *городище, страшилище или бородища*. По аналогии с *дымище, лбище, голосище или домище* слово **должно быть мужского рода**. Хотя какие-то колебания возможны, но в целом слова, образованные присоединением суффикса "-ищ(е)" и не обретшие при этом нового значения, сохраняют род исходного порождающего слова. Поэтому самое правильное будет использовать как несогласуемое приложение, то есть "не склонять". Итак, я предлагаю: ***подъехал к селу Столбище, выехал из села Столбище*** - и так далее.

Что касается "села Городище", то формально тут можно и согласовывать - и нет. Если "городище" это среднего рода, оно, то не склонять вроде бы нельзя (поскольку в правилах в явном виде иное не сказано). Ну а если Городище - это просто большой город? Тогда - он? Склонять не надо?
Но простите, кто будет разбираться со значением слова, породившего такой топоним? Поэтому и в этом случае я бы писал *подъехал к селу Городище, выехал из села Городище*. Вообще-то большинство носителей языка, видимо, так и поступают, но, к сожалению, в правилах тут некая лакуна, что позволяет придраться к любому варианту. Поэтому с топонимами типа *Городище, Пожарище, Гнездовище* и и некоторыми им подобными лучше быть максимально аккуратным, избегая вообще "сомнительных" падежей.

Comment: Чтобы не плодить похожих ответов, добавлю в комментарии косвенную аргументацию в пользу Вашего ответа. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Склонение_географических_названий_в_русском_языке) приводит противоречивые мнения профессиональных филологов по вопросу склонения топонимов среднего рода. Даже в этом случае некоторые из них считают, что с родовым словом топоним не склоняется, а без родового слова нормативны оба варианта. Думаю, что к топонимам на **-ище** это относится в неменьшей степени.

Comment: @grizzly Да, спасибо, я в курсе, что мнения на этот счет противоречивые, сама эта страничка на Вики, судя пор всему, своим появлением обязана именно этим спорам. Но мне прежде всего хотелось поднять не мнения, а аргументацию, с которой у "профессиональных филологов" последнее время наблюдается "напряженка". Влезать в спор, в котором ни одна из сторон не имеет каких-либо внятных аргументов, иных, чем "я так считаю", я бы не стал.

Comment: (+) Та же весьма мною уважаемая Лидия Коренеевна Чуковская (которую цитирует Jasmin) пишет такое, что заставляет усомниться в её понимании сити проблемы. Правда написано сие было, если не ошибаюсь в середине 70-х, а с тех пор много воды утекло... Но проблема-то и тогда и сейчас не в каком-то официозе стиля вообще, а в грамматике конкретных образований, созданных по парадигме притяжательных. С них все и началось. Впрочем, к Селищу и Городищу это  вообще отношения не имеет - но тут уж на Лидию Корнеевну валить не получается, она про этот тип топонимов вообще не говорит..

Answer (score 1):

Склоняется по обычным правилам, почему бы нет? То есть: склоняется, когда употребляется без родового слова. Выехал из Столбища. Но: выехал из села Столбище.

Comment: Если вдруг Вы не прочитали вопрос до конца: **со ссылкой на соответствующие правила русского языка**.

Comment: @grizzly я отчасти согласен с вашим замечанием, аргументация у Niemand'а все равно что никакая. Но ту-то дело в том, что естественное использование происходит скорее вопреки правилам , отсюда и предлагаемое несогласование "из сел**а** Столбищ**е**". Подробности - у меня в тексте ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Топонимы ***Столбище, Городище*** склоняются так же, как нарицательные существительные с суффиксом ИЩ, например ***городище***.

Вопрос о склонении таких названий обычно возникает при наличии приложения (село), в этом случае склоняемость регулируется **правилом Розенталя** [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_07](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_07)

**§197. Приложения – географические названия**

1. Названия городов, сел, деревень, поселков, усадеб, выраженные склоняемым существительным, **как правило, согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом,** например: в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом; в деревню Дюевку, через хутор Подбанку, в селе Ильинском.
2. **Не согласуются** вышеприведенные названия, если они выражены:
   1)      словосочетанием – в городе Кривой Рог, из села Чистый Ключ;
   2)      формой множественного числа – из города Черкассы, через хутор Большие Кузьмичи;
   3)      именами собственными, род которых не совпадает с основным понятием – в городе Ровно, у деревни Берестечко, в селе Углянец;
   4)      именами собственными на -ово(-ёво), -ыно(-ино) – в городе Иваново, из поселка Пушкино
3. Названия **местечек, аулов, кишлаков, застав** не согласуются с родовым наименованием, например: в местечке Ельск, недалеко от аула Арысыпай, в кишлаке Гилян.

Как видно из правила, название ***село Столбище*** к исключениям не относится и **должно склоняться даже при наличии родового слова.**

Правильно: **из Столбища, из села Столбища.**

**Примечание** (почему иногда не склоняют топонимы)

*Сколько времени посылка идет в Москву из Столбище.* Это ошибочное написание, но почему так пишут?  Обычно не склоняют географические названия на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, и здесь действительно допускаются варианты. Подробно об этом можно прочитать в следующей статье

http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy

Цитата в тему: **«Привычка не склонять названия местности берет свое начало, по-видимому, из военных сводок.** Но хорошо ли, что газета распространяет, укореняет эту привычку? "Я живу в Одинцово, в Кратово", а не "в Одинцове, в Кратове" – такая форма придает живой речи какой-то официальный характер» (Л. К. Чуковская. В лаборатории редактора).

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве вступления**

Недавно мы обсуждали виды вопросов (ромашку Блюма), и многие согласились с тем, что затея эта вредная и для нашей школы ненужная. Но у нас сайт вопросов и ответов, поэтому понимание семантики вопросов нам необходимо.

Как **правильно** — это прямой (простой) вопрос, он означает следующее: какая форма соответствует **правилам** русского языка (желательно указать источник)?

Есть еще вопросы-мнения (как вы считаете), **но на прямой вопрос надо давать прямой ответ:** в соответствии с правилами русского языка нужно использовать следующее написание...

**Ответ на вопрос**

1. В специальной (географической) литературе топонимы не склоняются с целью их точного воспроизведения.
2. В обычной литературе действуют **правила (они изложены у Розенталя),** по которым определяется склоняемость конкретного названия.
3. Но существует еще ***узус***  (лат. usus «применение, обычай) — общепринятое носителями данного языка употребление языковых единиц (слов, устойчивых оборотов, форм, конструкций).

Если usus вступает в противоречие с нормами (это, вероятно, определяется по частотности употребления), то в среде носителей языка появляются сомнения в правильности какой-либо формы, а **в правила могут вноситься изменения, поправки, а также допускается вариативность форм.**

4. В нашем случае вариативность возможна для названий на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно. Чем они особенные? Если коротко, то при склонении могут не различаться такие названия, как  город Пушкин и город Пушкино.
5. **Суть правила как раз и заключается в том, чтобы обеспечить узнаваемость начальной формы топонима**. По правилам ***Столбище*** должно склоняться.

Чтобы убедиться в корректности такого решения, рассмотрим возможные варианты названия: Столбище, Столбищи. При склонении они будут различаться: из Столбища, из Стролбищ. **Значит, существующее правило вполне корректно и поправок не требует.**

6. Реальнй вопрос (из Сети): **Сколько времени идет посылка из Столбище/Столбища в Москву?**

**Ответ-мнение:** Мне кажется, что название надо склонять, так как несклоняемая форма звучит непривычно. Или приводится другое мнение с его обоснованием.

**Прямой ответ:** Название склоняется в соответствии с правилами Розенталя, поправки к этому правилу в данном случае не требуются.

7. Итак, по всем правилам ***Столбище*** никак не относится к несклоняемым вариантам, но тем не менее его пытаются не склонять. Вероятно, это связано с общей тенденцией к несклоняемости **названий среднего рода** (по аналогии с названиями на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно).

Но, как говорит Зализняк А.А., "если степень распространения этого явления будет значительна", то возможны изменения, а именно названия ср. рода  могут приблизиться к статусу допустимого варианта (скорее всего,  в такой последовательности: сначала ***из села Столбище***, потом **из Столбище).**

Также следует учитывать, что **малая известность населенного пункта усиливает тенденцию к несклоняемости.**

Возможно, изменения в правилах уже приблизились, и нужно допустить варианты  *из села Столбище/Столбища*, так как они реально используются в силу ряда уже рассмотренных причин (общая тенденция к несклоняемости сущ. ср. рода, не слишком известное название, влияние военных сводок на общий процесс и т.д.).

**ВЫВОД**

**Но надо называть истинное положение вещей**: вот правило, вот мнения филологов, вот тенденция к изменению определенной группы топонимов, реально существующая, но еще официально не обозначенная в правилах.

**Что не надо делать, так это рассматривать каждое слово в отдельности и придумывать обоснование для его несклоняемости.**

Надо провести границу между ответом-мнением и прямым ответом на вопрос.